# Histogram with R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a vector of calls made on each days of a certain month.

```
callsperDayforMonth <- c(3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 9, 1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 9, 13, 15, 2, 5, 5, 2, 7, 3, 0, 1, 2, 7, 1, 8, 6, 9, 4)
```

I also have a vector of factors which spans the range of the "callsperDayforMonth" vector.

```
"0-2"   "3-5"   "6-8"   "9-11"  "12-14" "16+"
```

I need to create a histogram, with the factors on the horizontal axis.

How can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

The `hist` command has an argument `breaks` that can be a vector of the breakpoints to be used.  That should do what you want.

Or you could use `table` and `cut` to do the counts yourself and create a `barplot` from the result.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

cuts <- cut(callsperDayforMonth, 
    breaks = c(-Inf,2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 16, Inf),
    labels = c("0-2", "3-5", "6-8", "9-11", "12-14", "15-16", "16+"))
df <- data.frame(cuts, callsperDayforMonth)
ggplot(df, aes(x=cuts)) + geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

Comment: That is really not a histogram (but may be what the original poster intended).  Generally the bars in a histogram are touching and when the widths of the groups are unequal a histogram should represent this in the width of the bars and scale the y-coordinates so that the areas still represent the values of interest.

Comment: Yeah from the description it seemed more like a bar chart.